# Removing self signed certificate from my store

Tags: ssl, powershell

Is there a way to remove/ uninstall a self signed certificate from my store using powershell ?

I tried

```
Remove-Item cert:\LocalMachine\My\$thumb
```

it did not work, I got an exception saying "Provider does not support this operation"

I also tried

```
 certmgr.msc /del /n "MyTestServer" /s MY
```

it did not work either

How can I uninstall certificate from store ??

Thanks in advance
Jeez

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This approach seems to apply to Powershell 2 only and thus it is outdated.**

Remove-Item does not work with certificates because der cert-provider is readonly in powershell. Found that information [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/08/23/removing-certificates-from-the-certificate-store/)

```
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509Store 'My','CurrentUser'
$store.Open('ReadWrite')
$certs = @(dir cert:\currentuser\my | ? { $_.Subject -like '*MyTestServer*' })
foreach ($cert in $certs) {$store.Remove($cert)}
$store.close()
```

I found the solution [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347615.aspx) in the comments. So it is untested.

Comment: From PowerShell 3.0 and forward this approach is sub-optimal.  See the answers below for a better solution.

Comment: @JasonWeber True, but in 2011 JeeZ had no access to Powershell 3.

Answer (score 6):

Found this article because remove-item wasn't working.

This is not exactly 'true' powershell, but I use this method:

```
certutil -delstore my "5314bdfa0255be36e53e749d033"
```

You can get thumbprint via cert:\LocalMachine\my or through certutil. In my case, I have multiple certs with exact same name, so I like above method more because it gives me a specific target when I delete a cert.

Answer (score 6):

With PS 3.0, if you want to remove by subjectName

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | where { $_.subject -eq "CN=MysubjectName" } | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 4):

With PS 3.0 there is a more concise and idiomatic approach:

`Remove-Item -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\{Thumbprint} -DeleteKey`

See [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847855(v=wps.620).aspx) for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

This will work as well in powershell

To get the thumbpeint
dir cert:\localmachine\my

To delete the thumbprint
del cert:\localmachine\my\thumbprint

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is an old thread, but since I'm looking at doing the same right now thought I'd post. I'm needing to remove from all cert stores by friendly name.

Realise this isn't the answer for OP but may help someone.

If that is required by anyone this works for me `dir cert: -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -like "*SOMENAME*" } | Remove-Item`

Answer (score 0):

You are set on wrong cert store

Use `$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\THUMBPRINT"` instead of `cert:\LocalMachine\My\$thumb` you say that the certificates are your. So your certificates are stored in `-Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\THUMBPRINT"` CurrentUser = Your user account, and you don't need to change it to your account name.

br.